# Visualizing Backpropogation - Minimizing Errors in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I have been trying to think of exactly how backpropogation in a neural network works, what the derivative is, and what function it is trying to minimize.

Below I tried to make the simplest model I could, an input, hidden, and output layer with 1 node in each, represented by a().  The network uses a sigmoid function, w() is the weights between each node.  We calculate each of the deltas, then update the weights accordingly.  Please let me know if I have made any errors in my model.

My question is, what exactly are we trying to minimize?  We are trying to minimize the delta for each node, correct?  Delta does not seem to be the derivative of anything, I know that x*(1-x) is the derivative of the logistic function (1/1+e^-x), but for delta(a1) a(1) is the x in this case and it would not be the x in the sigmoid function for a(1)..  And if delta(a1) is a derivative, what function is it a derivative of exactly?

```
Input          Hidden          Output
a(0) ---w(1)--- a(1) ---w(2)--- a(3)

delta(a2) = a(2) - y

delta(a1) = [delta(a2) * w(2)] * a(1) * [1 - a(1)]

w1 = w1 - [a(0) * delta(a1)]

w2 = w2 - [a(1) * delta(a2)]
```

Comment: IIRC, The objective you're trying to minimize is always the squared error in the output nodes, where you have a target value. All derivatives are w.r.t to that output error. Backpropagation is just an elegant way to calculate the derivatives of the hidden nodes, but if you used the chain rule, you'd get exactly the same derivatives.

Comment: I think, delta(a2) in your example is the derivative of the error function. Therefore we are trying the minimize the error function value.